# Kubernetes persistent volume resize

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes

What would a be good approach to fix storage issues when your services run out of the presistent volume free space?

For example I have a gitlab service running on kubernetes installed with Helm Chart.
I have used the default settings, but now I ran out of free space for gitlab. 
What would be the ideal approach to fix this issue?

- Is there anyway I can increase the PV in size?
- Should I somehow backup the gitlab data, recreate it with more storage?
- Can I somehow backup and restore data from PV-s so there is no dataloss?
  I am open to any suggestion about how to deal with the issue when your PersistentVolume is getting full!

Thank you for your answers,
Bence Pjatacsuk

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can increase the PV in size?

There is no official way to increase PV size in Kubernetes for now, actually I don't think this is Kubernetes' responsibility. [Here's the related issue.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35941)

But you can increase it manually in two steps:

1. Increase PV size in the backend storage, eg. [resize GCE pd](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd)
2. Change that PV size definition in Kubernetes cluster, eg. `kubectl edit pv <pv_id>`

As for data backup and restore, it depends on your backend storage. You can backup your PV (eg. create a snapshot) -> create a new one based on it -> and increase the size -> create a new pod with same definition but bind the larger size PV to it.

Comment: Thanks, we are using NTFS for backend on baremetal. 
Unfortunatly the company can't use any cloud provider, so we have to do everything on baremetal.